# Java Geocoding - convert latitude and longitude into an address

Tags: java, android, google-geocoder

I need for my Android App the name of the city where my car is located in the moment.

I have the latitude and longitude and want to convert this with the geocoder in the address and want to get the city.

I read some blocks but because I'm new to this I dont get the clue.

Please can anyone help me how to do this?

**EDIT:**

I dont use this geocoding in my app. I want to use it in my Java web service and I think I have to this with HTTPRequest, is it? and with the google api url.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/. And look at the reverse Geocoding section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Reverse Geocoding`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding).

The [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class should help you do what you need (taken from [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/reverse-geocoding)):

```
public static void getAddressFromLocation(
        final Location location, final Context context, final Handler handler) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override public void run() {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());   
            String result = null;
            try {
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = list.get(0);
                    // sending back first address line and locality
                    result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
            } finally {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.setTarget(handler);
                if (result != null) {
                    msg.what = 1;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("address", result);
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                } else 
                    msg.what = 0;
                msg.sendToTarget();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

EDIT: As per your comment, then no, you can't use the `Geocoder` class on a normal Java web service. That being said, there are alternatives. The [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) is usually a good place to start, that being said, they do seem to have [limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits).

Alternatively, you could take a look at [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) which is an open source Reverse Geocoding service albeit it seems to be slightly limited when compared to Google's services.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say. I dont use this geocoding in my app. I have a java web service and there I cant use `Geocoder', is it? I have to request over httprequest and the google api,  i think.

Comment: @aut_silvia: I have updated my answer. I hope this makes things clearer for you.

Comment: @JonathanRamos: To be honest, this code is not my own, hence I included the source. That being said, certain tasks, such as resource acquisitions (GPS co-ordinates, file downloads, etc) need to be on a separate thread on GUI applications since hosting them on the main thread will usually hang the UI, which degrades user-application interaction and in some cases the phone might also close the application.